# How best to construct an indicator variable to capture the effects of an intervention?

Tags: time-series, intervention-analysis, macroeconomics

How should one construct an indicator variable to properly capture the effects of an intervention?
If an intervention like the 2008 bailout (TARP-Economic stimulus) is to get proper credit for the current recovery, how would one specify this intervention in a regression model?
Assume, I have monthly time-series data and I want to understand several causal factors influence on some economic recovery measure (e.g. GDP).
One causal factor maybe the economic stimulus that Obama signed into law. Given other factors, how much credit should this intervention get?
Say the economic stimulus bill was signed into law September 2008, should I create a indicator that assigns a 1 to that month and a 0 for all the months before and after September 2008? If the program lasted 10 months, should I assign a 1 to those 10 months and o to the months both and after that period?
Would the second approach take to much credit for the recovery away from other continuous predictors in a linear regression model?